# Best Sensor for obtaining types of objects at a distance

Tags: sensor, camera, video, spectrum-analyzer

I could not completely describe the sensor required in the title,

what I am looking for is a sensor that can pick up if there is a different material, from a preconfigured material type, lets say in a area of 10x40 meters infront of the sensor.

- Example:
  There is a grass field with random blocks where there are no grass.

I have thought of using maybe a colour spectrum sensor of some kind; or even using low resolution video footage and using software to analyze the contents.

***There will always be a set value ( the grass in this case ), that is compared to a range of different values (blocks without grass, or patches of dirt etc.****

What I am trying to achieve is to draw a graphical representation of where the grass is.

Thanks for any guidance

Comment: I'm thinking your sensor is called a camera, of one kind or another.

Comment: yes, use a camera and some simple computer vision, and flood-fill for the grassy area to get where all the grass is. You can use simple classifiers for grass, entirely on colour if you wanted. There are algorithms such as "K Nearest Neighbour" which are used to make the flood-fill of the image, finding all the grass in the picture.

Answer (score 1):

Use a camera and some simple computer vision, and flood-fill for the grassy area to get where all the grass is. You can use simple classifiers for grass, entirely on colour if you wanted. There are algorithms such as "K Nearest Neighbour" which are used to make the flood-fill of the image, finding all the grass in the picture.

The patches which are NOT grass are just "any other object" but you can also run classifiers on these too, and you can end up with different coloured blobs in the final image showing where things like grass, blue boxes, small red children, and even a white sheep!

This is a common technique for obstacle detection and classification/avoidance in mobile robotics, which might help you research more into these computer/robot/machine vision issues.

Answer (score -1):

To complete your project you should depend on the frequency of the materials that you want to detect. 
Like (metal detector)

Comment: This is too thin and vague for an answer on EE.SE.  Please elaborate.

Comment: You can send the suitable frequency for the materials you want to detect using a coil with frequency generator circuit and read the reflection signal throw another coil , so you can calculat the distance and the material.